# Arithmetic overflow error for type in Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In an SQL SERVER 2000 table,there is a column called `Kpi of float type`.
when try to convert that column to `varchar(cast(kpi as varchar(3)))`,It gives an error

```
Msg 232, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 26.100000.
```

The thing is the column has only one distinct value and that is 26.1.
I can not understand why does it show error when converting it into varchar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error has triggered by full stop in 26.1.

you have applied this command:

```
cast(kpi as varchar(3))
```

First: change cast from varchar(3) to varchar(4) (to get the first value after full stop)

So you'll have:

This line convert value 26.10000000 in 26.1

Then you apply `varchar(26.1)` not correct!

Varchar type wants only integer value as size.

Why you apply the last varchar?? I think you must to remove the external varchar and leave only cast function

Comment: Now i understood the error...the thing is different than you have mentioned...thanks for the help

Comment: @user1254579,you should always share the solution even if you solve it of your own .

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
declare @x float = 26.1
select left(@x,3)
```

Result will be 26.

Answer (score 1):

The distinct value is 26.1 ,which is **4 character** length and the attempt was to cast it to cast(kpi as varchar(3))...If  change it to **cast(kpi as varchar(4))** it would work and ll get 26.1